# search in column 1 of the text file shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

this is to remove employee from the data.txt file.  after the user input the ID to be removed, i want to program to just search the first column of the file (which is the Emp ID column) not the whole file's data .
i've written the code, but it seems that it will search all the data in the txt file.

how can i improve it ?

code:

```
  Payroll =data.txt
   echo
   echo "[Option: $input]"
   echo -e "${UBlue}Removing employee record: "
   echo -e "Please enter the employee's ID.${NoColor}"
   echo
   echo -en "Employee ID: "
   read empid_search

   if [ `count_lines "^${empid_search},"` -eq 0 ]
   then
       echo "Error: This particular record does not exist!!"
   else
       echo "Please verify removal of this employee's record: " 
       echo -en "Employee's Details: "
       locate_lines "^${empid_search}"     

       confirm "Confirm remove?[y/n]" 
       if [ $? -ne 0 ]
       then
          echo "Entry has not been deleted.."  
       else
          cp $PAYROLL tmpfile
          grep -vi "$empid_search" tmpfile > $PAYROLL ; rm tmpfile
          echo "Entry is deleted from records.."
       fi           
   fi

   echo -en "Hit [Enter] to return to main menu..."
   read
```

Text file:

```
1,James,Manager,Admin,1300
2,Sally,Executive,Sales,2000
3,John,CEO,xpy,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just missing `^` and `,` in the grep command.

```
grep -vi "^${empid_search}," tmpfile > $PAYROLL
```

Note: It's better practice to enclose variable name in `{}`

---

Also try using `sed`. It can do in-place delete avoiding need of *tmpfile*

```
sed -i "/^${empid_search},/d" $PAYROLL
```

---

Another variation using `awk`. More robust when dealing with well formatted *csv* files.

```
awk -F, '$1!="'${empid_search}'"' tmpfile > $PAYROLL
```

Comment: just any question, i try searching by name, it also work.. by right it should let user search by name in the EmpID_search.
any idea? thanks

Comment: @Alien in such case `awk` is better way. `$1` contains ID and `$2` contains name. Try `awk -F, '$1!="'${empid_search}'" && $2!="'${empid_search}'"' tmpfile`

Comment: if i got empid (eg. 1, 10 or 11) when i key in 1 to remove the empid 1, all the 3 other emp details will be deleted :\ im not too sure why

Comment: @Alien Oops, I missed it! check my updated ans with `,`. Please note the `awk` will work in any case. Prefer it when you have well formatted `csv` file.

Comment: thanks, im using the awk now but not sure how come it doesnt work with checking the exact number, sorry not too familiar with this.

Comment: @Alien for ID `1` and search `^1` matched everything starting from `1` so 1, 10, 11 etc.. in updated ans I've changed match string to `^1,` so it can't match 10, 11.. refer to [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for more details and learning. hope it helps.